# Jenkins: How do I set up the mailer plug-in to use Outlook.com account?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-mailer-plugin

The question is quite simple (yet, I don't get it to work):

Which steps are required for the Jenkins mailer plug-in to use an Outlook.com (aka Hotmail) account?

My Jenkins is installed locally on a stand-alone Windows 10x64 VM with unrestricted access to the Internet.

EDIT:

Let's assume I didn't enter anything yet. Just fill in the fields below with valid values (except User Name and Password) and add any steps to make things work (incl. absolute paths to config files touched, XML nodes' XPath, whatever):

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You got some credentials and an SMTP server address?

Comment: Please refer to my edit.

Comment: Servers usually don't accept mail from your home internet connection.  So you most likely need to enter an SMTP server address (which accepts your user name and password).

Comment: Absolutely. That'd be the first line in the form depicted above.